# How to make sense of cluster with PCA which consist of more than two PCs?

Tags: r, clustering, python, pca

I would need to use more than three principal components in order to have 80% information of my data set based on my plot below. Is there an effective way to do cluster analysis with more than three principal components?

EDIT:
Most of the examples on Internet are plots with just PCA1 vs PCA2 where the two components explains majority of the information. I don't believe that in commercial companies it is that easy.

[image]

Comment: Why is doing cluster analysis not "effective" with 4+ components?

Comment: There are *visual* methods based on biplots of pairs of components, for instance: is this the sort of thing you're looking for?

Comment: You can do clustering in more than 3 dimensions, you just can't visualize it.

Comment: Welcome to CV.  Cluster just means "can I put it in the same box as some of its friends".  You can do that in all kinds of dimensions.  K-means is relatively quick even in some higher-than-2 dimensions, as long as you know how many different bins you want to have.  Euclidean nearest neighbors is not a bad way of looking at membership either.  PCA in R handles all kinds of dimensions, but pointy-haired (Dilbert-style) bosses do not.